# Start remaining futures without blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

I have a loop over a set where I have to perform an expensive calculation. I want to do this in parallel using the future class. As far as I understand this, async either starts the thread or defers it and starts it only when I call get() or wait(). So, when I have threads not started and try to get the result, I block the main thread an get a sequential processing. Is there a way to start the remaining deferred processes, so everything is calculated in parallel and will not block when I call get().

```
// do the calculations
std::vector<std::future<class>> futureList;
for (auto elem : container)
{
  futureList.push_back(std::async(fct, elem));
}

// start remaining processes

// use the results
for (auto elem : futureList)
{
  processResult(elem.get())
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could always poll the future to see if it is ready? To do that you might [wait for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) zero time, and see if there's a result ready or not.

Comment: How will starting the remaining threads help? You still have to wait for them to finish. If you have other stuff you can do in parallel, then launch that in a different `async` task.

Comment: I have 100 calculation, so only a few start directly. The rest only start, when I call wait() or get(). If I use than get(), this will only start one task and block the main task. I have nothing else to do in this function.

Comment: You're missing `std::launch::async`. Try passing that in as the first argument to `std::async`. After that, @juanchopanza is correct, you still have to wait for them to finish :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, fct, elem)
```

Sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

bool work() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    if( ! (std::rand() % 2)) throw std::runtime_error("Exception");
    return true;
}

int main() {
    const unsigned Elements = 10;

    typedef std::vector<std::future<bool>> future_container;
    future_container futures;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < Elements; ++i)
    {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, work));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }

    while( ! futures.empty()) {
        future_container::iterator f = futures.begin();
        while(f != futures.end())
        {
            if(f->wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100)) == std::future_status::timeout) ++f;
            else {
                // Note:: Exception resulting due to the invokation of 
                //        the thread are thrown here.
                //        (See 30.6.6 Class template future)
                try {
                    std::cout << f->get() << '\n';
                }
                catch(const std::exception& e) {
                    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
                }
                f = futures.erase(f);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this throws an exception, if the task cannot be created, not what I want.

Comment: @user2988020 What exception?

Comment: system_error or errc::resource_unavailable_try_again

Comment: @user2988020 If you are using g++ you might have to make sure the option -pthread is set and you are linking against pthread

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like : (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/005c7d2345ad791c)

Create this function:

```
void processResult_async(std::future<myClass>& f) { processResult(f.get()); }
```

And then

```
// use the results
std::vector<std::future<void>> results;
for (auto& elem : futureList)
{
    results.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, processResult_async, std::ref(elem)));
}
```